# Lifecycle method inside another one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I wanted to know your opinion whether is a best practice or not to use a lifecycle hook inside another.
For example - set an observer when component is mounted, then unobserve when onBeforeUnmount.

```
onMounted(() => {
observe code

onBeforeUnmount(() => unobserve)
})
```

An alternative would be -

```
onMounted(() => {
observe code
})

onBeforeUnmount(() => unobserve)
```

What is the right approach?
Thanks.

Comment: second one is the right approach.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It's not about preference. Only the second snippet is correct. Composition api is supposed to be used directly inside setup function, unless it's known that it's not (ref, reactive, etc were designed to be used outside a component).

Comment: @EstusFlask *technically*, you *can* call lifecycle hooks outside of `setup`. Refer: [Do note this doesn't mean that the call must be placed lexically inside `setup()` or `<script setup>`. `onMounted()` can be called in an external function as long as the call stack is synchronous and originates from within `setup()`.](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#registering-lifecycle-hooks) But it is important to guarantee that they are synchronous. I see no point in calling `onBeforeUnmount` in `onMounted` unless `onMounted` itself is also only conditionally called.